# Xamarin maximum grid row/ column definitions

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, roguelike

I've only started playing with xamarin recently but I'm making a roguelike using xamarin and I had the idea of using a grid for the player map (each X Y position in the grid would be representing the randomly generated map) I've hit a snag though in that putting things any thing over the 55th column seems to push them off the screen (See image below)
[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
           Grid grid = new Grid
           {
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
           };
           stackLayout.Children.Add(grid);

           for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
           {
               grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
               grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
           }
           

           // Row 0
           // The BoxView and Label are in row 0 and column 0, and so only needs to be added to the
           // Grid.Children collection to get default row and column settings.
           grid.Children.Add(new BoxView
           {
               Color = Color.Green
           });
           grid.Children.Add(new Label
           {
               Text = "Row 0, Column 0",
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
           });

           // This BoxView and Label are in row 0 and column 1, which are specified as arguments
           // to the Add method.
           grid.Children.Add(new BoxView
           {
               Color = Color.Blue
           }, 55, 0);
           grid.Children.Add(new Label
           {
               Text = "Row 0, Column 1",
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
           }, 1, 0);

           // Row 1
           // This BoxView and Label are in row 1 and column 0, which are specified as arguments
           // to the Add method overload.
           grid.Children.Add(new BoxView
           {
               Color = Color.Teal
           }, 0, 1, 1, 2);
           grid.Children.Add(new Label
           {
               Text = "Row 1, Column 0",
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
           }, 0, 1, 1, 2); // These arguments indicate that that the child element goes in the column starting at 0 but ending before 1.
                           // They also indicate that the child element goes in the row starting at 1 but ending before 2.

           grid.Children.Add(new BoxView
           {
               Color = Color.Purple
           }, 1, 2, 1, 2);
           grid.Children.Add(new Label
           {
               Text = "Row1, Column 1",
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
           }, 1, 2, 1, 2);

           // Row 2
           // Alternatively, the BoxView and Label can be positioned in cells with the Grid.SetRow
           // and Grid.SetColumn methods.
           BoxView boxView = new BoxView { Color = Color.Red };
           Grid.SetRow(boxView, 2);
           Grid.SetColumnSpan(boxView, 2);
           Label label = new Label
           {
               Text = "Row 2, Column 0 and 1",
               HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
               VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
           };
           Grid.SetRow(label, 2);
           Grid.SetColumnSpan(label, 2);

           grid.Children.Add(boxView);
           grid.Children.Add(label);

           Title = "Basic Grid demo";
           Content = grid;
```

So I guess the question is a few folds, how can I "Zoom" out on the grid view to see the other cells of the grid? Additionally, am I even going about this the right way ? or is there a better approach that using a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should warp the content into a [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scrollview-as-a-root-layout) and set `Content = scrollView`, then you can scroll to see all the elements:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };


        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        stackLayout.Children.Add(grid);

        //......
        
        grid.Children.Add(boxView);
        grid.Children.Add(label);

        Title = "Basic Grid demo";

        //warp the content into a ScrollView 
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView { Content = stackLayout };
        scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both;

        Content = scrollView;
    }
```

Comment: Hi jack, thanks for the reply. This is quite close to what i'm looking for (I'm going to mark it as the answer as for the moment it fulfils what I want), I assume there's also a way to make this scroll view zoomable? (With the scrollview they can move their viewport around the map and It would be useful for players to get an overview of the map they are on to try plan out their path/how to use their resources)
No worries if you don't know offhand and thanks for the reply :)